# Append to each element in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

With an array, how would I append a character to each element in the array? I want to add the string ":" after each element and then print the result.

```
 var a = [54375, 54376, 54377, 54378, 54379, 54380, 54381, 54382, 54383, 54384, 54385, 54386, 54387, 54388, 54389, 54390, 54391, 54392, 54393, 54394, 54395, 54396, 54397, 54400, 54402, 54403, 54405, 54407, 54408];
```

For example: 54375:54376:54377

Comment: your question is ambiguous, do you want a concatenated string with all the numbers separated by colon (as in your example) or an array  a = [ "54375:", "54376:", "54377:", "54378:" ...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you are looking for a way to concatenate all the elements with `:`**, you can use this

```
var result = "";
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i += 1) {
    result += a[i] + ":";
}
result = result.substr(0, result.length-1);
```

Or even simpler, you can do

```
a = a.join(":");
```

**If you are looking for a way to append `:` to every element**, you can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), like this

```
a = a.map(function (currentItem) {
    return currentItem + ":";
});
console.log(a);
```

If your environment doesn't support `map` yet, then you can do this

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i += 1) {
    a[i] = a[i] + ":";
}
```

Comment: @VisioN Indeed. But I was just listing down the various ways to do this and `reduce` was the first one to come to my mind.

Comment: Well, there are many other extreme ways, e.g. `([123,345,456,567]+[':']).replace(/,/g, ':');`.

Comment: @VisioN I understand the sarcasm, but it should have been `['']` or `''` as per the OP's requirement and I removed the `reduce` version :)

Answer (score 5):

```
a = a.map(function(el) { return el + ':'; });
```

Or if you want to [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them into a string:

```
var joined = a.join(':');
```

Comment: I think the `join()` approach is what OP is after here.

Comment: `return a + ':'?`?!?!